# Does YARN calculate num-executors ever?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

What if I am just provide

```
u'--executor-cores', '5',
u'--executor-memory', '20G'
u'--driver-memory', '20G',
```

Will YARN automatically calculate the maximum number of Spark executors that could be placed in a cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** No. Hadoop YARN won't calculate num-executors (since it's already provided when you `spark-submit` a Spark application implicitly).

Execute `spark-submit --help` to read the description of `num-executors` (highlighting mine):

> YARN-only:
>
> --num-executors NUM         Number of executors to launch (**Default: 2**).

So, unless you specify the number you'll end up with 2 executors.

Note that `--num-executors` is for a single and entire Spark app and has nothing to do with the number of workers in use (that a YARN cluster manages).